# how to remove uncommon lines at beginning or end of the files?

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have two different files with the first column is common, the only difference may be missing or extra lines at the beginning or at the end of any file.

## file1

```
aaa 1
bbb 2
ccc 3
aaa 4
bbb 5
ddd 6
eee 7
fff 8
ggg 9
```

## file2

```
bbb 10
ccc 20
aaa 30
bbb 40
ddd 50
eee 60
fff 70
ggg 80
www 90
```

## outfile

```
bbb 2 10
ccc 3 20
aaa 4 30
bbb 5 40
ddd 6 50
eee 7 60
fff 8 70
ggg 9 80
```

I know how to print common lines using awk

`awk 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1] > 0' file1 file2`

but I need to print the common section of the two files as shown in outfile.

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort the files, use join command. 
Remember that using arrays in awk is not efficient, and with large files it can be very slow.

Comment: No, I can't use sort the files it has a specific sequence in the first column and it is same in both the files. The only things I need to remove a few uncommon lines at the begging or at the end of any of the files as described in the question.